# Problems with bibliography and references in TexWorks

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am writing a report in Latex, and I have the references in a separate bib file and I reference them in my main document as `\cite{xxx}`.

I am using Texworks on Windows. After compiling the bib to generate a bbl, when I compile the tex file with: "pdflatex + MakeIndex + BibTex", I am able to see the pdf the report, but I do not see the Bibilography section at the end and do not see references to the bibliography, not even question marks instead of the proper references to the bibliography.

I include the bibliography by typing

```
 \bibliography{plain}
```

and

```
 \bibliography{"C:/Users/BibName"}
```

at the end of the tex file

I then tried pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex + pdflatex. When I tried that, the 'References' section shows up at the end, but I do not see the references, such as

```
1. Reinhard, D.A. Case Study
```

I also do not see the citation in the paper

Here is the MWE:
The tex is:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  
Alpha particles \cite{example} (named after and denoted by the first letter in the
Greek alphabet,\[\alpha\]) consist of two protons and two neutrons bound
together.
This means that an particle is a helium nucleus. 

\bibliography{plain}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{BibName}

\end{document}
```

The bib is:

```
@article{example,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This *should* work. Since it's not, we'll require more information. What does the `.log` say? What about the output from BibTeX? Can you compose a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing?

Comment: I do see some errors in the output, such as `! LaTeX Error: File natbib.sty' not found.` and `todonotes.sty not found`, but I thought these were insignificant since it still produces the pdf at the end, containing everything as expected, except for the 'references' section

Comment: My MWE is now in the OP

Comment: Please read [this post](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) to see how to create a minimal example that includes the use of a bibliography.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I had no idea that is what an MWE should look like

Comment: The problem is that I cannot replicate your current situation, since I don't have `NameofBibFile.bib`. The [link](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) mentions you should create `\jobname.bib` as part of your MWE. Also, at the beginning of the post you mention the use of `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, while in your "MWE" you use `\bibliography{plain}` - an obvious mistake. Please read the linked post *complete*, then create a MWE that replicates your problem, and update your post.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I edited the OP and hope I didn't make any more mistakes

Comment: Okay, so now my question is... do you use `\bibliographystyle` at all?

Comment: I have not tried `\bibliographystyle` yet. I just want to be able to compile the bib file with the tex file. If it is required to use `\bibliographystyle`, then I will include it

Comment: The `\bibliographystyle` is required, since it specifies which `.bst` to use to create the `.bbl` from the `.bib`. Without it, BibTeX would not now how to format the bibliography. You should also see this being reported as problematic in the BibTeX output (or your `.blg` file).

Comment: I edited the OP to include `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, and after including it in my tex and compiling, I still don't see anything in the `References` section

Comment: Drop *entirely* `\bibliography{plain}` and use *only* `\bibliographystyle{plain} \bibliography{<bibname>}`.

Answer (score 2):

`\bibliography{<file>}` denotes the name of the `<file>.bib` that contains your BibTeX references, while `\bibliographystyle{<bibstyle>}` denotes the style you want your references displayed in. You clearly want one `\bibliography` only:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{example,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The {\TeX} book},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}  
Alpha particles~\cite{example} (named after and denoted by the first letter in the
Greek alphabet,~$\alpha$) consist of two protons and two neutrons bound
together. This means that an particle is a helium nucleus. 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps (something really basic that maybe you already did, but if don't it can crack your head off).

Try avoiding spaces in names of .tex and .bib, both. It generates names with spaces also in `.aux`, `.bbl` etc.

I had the same problem: Long .tex and .bib files with a final .pdf with question marks instead of referencies, and messages like `Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "XXXX"` and `Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.`. No `.bbl` at all and no answer about when surfing the web.

At the end, I just copy/paste everything to a new folder in new files (trying to avoid unknown characters) and changed even names. It magically worked just because the new name didn't have spaces (`test.tex` instead of `pritty work for my lovely boss v_342.tex`).

N. of R.: I'm working under Windows and this happend to me only using TeXworks. In an old PC (also under Windows plattform), that I don't use because it has less reaction than a slug, it works perfectly even with spaces in names, so I suppose that is because I had TeXnicCenter in my old PC. BTW, using TeXnicCenter you just have to compile several times but with a unique compiling option (LaTeX=>PDF); using TeXworks you have to compile with pdfLaTeX, then with BibTeX and finally twice with pdfLaTex again, always the .tex file.